# PHP - Trying to display Mysql results on new line

Tags: php

Trying to figure out how to make it so results stop displaying as one monolithic row but are instead each on their own line. Not having much luck thus far.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ROUND(score) AS performance FROM images ORDER BY ROUND(score) DESC LIMIT 11,50");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $top_ratings2[] = (object) $row;
}


<? foreach($top_ratings2 as $key => $image) : ?>
<td valign="top">
  <b><?=$image->name?></b>
  <b>Score:</b> <?=$image->score?>
  <b>Wins:</b> <?=$image->wins?> 
</td>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Answer (score 0):

try using a table

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ROUND(score) AS performance FROM images ORDER BY ROUND(score) DESC LIMIT 11,50");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $top_ratings2[] = (object)$row;
}
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Wins</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($top_ratings2 as $key => $image) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <?= $image->name ?>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <?= $image->score ?>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <?= $image->wins ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```